# Does being connected to wifi not drain any battery whatsoever if it's not being used?

Tags: wi-fi, samsung, battery, android-11

I have the samsung a32 5g.

I tested my phone with wifi connected while doing nothing, and it didn't move even 1 percent after an hour.

Does being connected to wifi use up no power at all if it's not actually being used, or does it to a certain degree? It would just take maybe the whole day to get 1-2% drained if little to no wifi usage is actually being utilized?

If you're going to get updates and notifications with wifi on anyway, shouldn't you just keep it on all day at home?

Comment: If you keep Wifi enabled at home is your decision. Staying connected requires a little powerandalso the apps using network in background need power, too. But modern Android versions are very efficient in sleep mode. Therefore just monitor batter Ausgabe and decide if to keep on wifi or not.

Comment: Thanks, I meant staying connected. I do notice there is some background activity but battery drain is very minimal. Would you personally say keeping it on all day is not a big drain to battery? Other than manually checking, how can you find out how much battery usage it takes up by just being connected?

Comment: Use your phone one week with always on Wifi and one week without and compare battery usage e.g. over night.